# Role for referencing source code in repository

Tags: repository, python-sphinx

Is there a way to reference source files (file and line) in the source repository, without writing the repo URL in the ReST explicitly? Something like

```
# conf.py:
repo_root="http://github.com/some/project"

# something.rst
A good example of this is found in :repo:`examples/ex1.py`/ or :repo:`examples/ex1.py`.
```

Comment: Seems like you could use this: http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/extlinks.html.

Comment: @mzjn: thanks. Can you give it as answer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [sphinx.ext.extlinks](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/extlinks.html) extension. Example:

```
extlinks = {'repo': ('http://github.com/some/project/%s', 'repo ')}
```